# Use of createSelectorHook instead of deprecated TypedUseSelectorHook

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux

I had the following code to define a typed selector with Redux in TypeScript:

```
import { useSelector, TypedUseSelectorHook } from 'react-redux';

export interface RootState {
    user: {
        account: string;
    }
};

export const useTypedSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```

Now I see that `TypedUseSelectorHook` is deprecated and should be replaced by `createSelectorHook<State, Action>()`.

Not sure how to change it and if `Action` must be there as well. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `useSelector` hook has two generic variables: the type of the entire state (`TState`) and the type of the value which you are selecting (`TSelected`).  We want to make a bound hook where `TState` is known, but `TSelected` varies depending on the selector argument that we call the hook with.

`TypedUseSelectorHook` is basically just a typescript override.  The value of your `useTypedSelector` is just `useSelector`.

`createSelectorHook` is a little bit different because it's a factory function which returns a `useSelector` hook.  It takes a context as an optional argument [(docs link)](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#custom-context) and it has a second generic variable for `Action` because that `context` depends on the action type.  Your selector hook doesn't depend on the action type so you don't need to worry about it.  Luckily the `Action` variable is optional and defaults to `AnyAction`.  You just need to set the generic for the state:

```
export const useTypedSelector = createSelectorHook<RootState>();
```

The type for `useTypedSelector` is what we expect, which is a hook with only one generic describing the selected value:

```
const useTypedSelector: <Selected extends unknown>(
  selector: (state: RootState) => Selected, 
  equalityFn?: ((previous: Selected, next: Selected) => boolean) | undefined
) => Selected
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYygUwIYzQZTQGzWRmgAkIIBrOAXzgDMoIQ4BydDYgWnQBMBXAB6sA3AFgAUJLSDIsOMAB22KPU5o4AJQowcMLBoSS4JuPwDOaKAC5Ex0w87II-ZbfMwoSgObiJDmkkaP2lZaHhnRQ8zSwAVAE8wNF48QmJoOABeFA5sVKISKHIqAB5tCF19bAA%20AAoAShEgA)

Comment: does this apply to version 7.2.2?

Comment: @Daniel I found out that `TypedUseSelectorHook` was deprecated accidentally.  It's recommended that you use `TypedUseSelectorHook` instead of `createSelectorHook`.

Comment: I just found that out myself as well :)